# Problem with int(input) and except ValueError

Tags: python-3.x

I try to validate user input if is integer not in a function.

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter the number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Try again. Input phone number, must containing digits. ')

    break

print (number)
```

If I enter number it works prints the number (however Pycharm tells me that variable number in last line might ve undefined) however when it crash instead asking for enter again:

```
Enter the number: s
Try again. Input phone number, must containing digits. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 9, in <module>
    print (number)
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

In a function it seems easier to make but in this case I'm lost.

Comment: if you break even if value error exception, number doesn't have a chance to be defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` means you leave the loop, even if you've had the ValueError, despite `number` not being assigned yet.

Instead of putting the break outside the `try`, have you considered putting it inside, so it only triggers if `number` gets assigned successfully?

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter the number: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Try again. Input phone number, must containing digits. ')

print(number)
```

Comment: ha, I solved it but in not as good way :-)

[code]
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input('Enter the number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Try again. Input phone number, must containing digits. ')

    else:
        break

print (number)
[code]